# DropDownList with Populate from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get a DropDownList to pull users and then allow me to filter them. I am on a project with many other people using the same controllers and views.  I need to somehow work my code in with theirs. I have this so far

```
**Controller**

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(string Person)
 { 
      var User = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == Person).First();
      IEnumerable<Job> MyJob from job in db.Jobswhere job.Schedules.Count > 0 && 
      job.Schedules.Person == User select job;

  }


**ViewIndex**

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("Person", ViewBag.Person as SelectList, "--Select Person--", new { style = "height:40px; width:450px; margin-bottom:10px" })
            <input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn btn-default" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-12">
```

I can get the Dropdown and Filter button to show up on the page, 
but I cannot get the functionality working. 
Any help is appreciated, I have been coding for 3 months only. I am very new.

Comment: In your "ViewIndex" you're getting data from ViewBag.Person, but you're not assigning anything to ViewBag.Person in your controller.

Comment: @DCCoder is correct you are no populating your `ViewBag.Person` give a look at this [tutotial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: Thank you I will go back and make those changes and go from there!

Comment: Would you guys have any idea on how to assign it? I have been searching for hours trying to get this to work to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not assigning anything to ViewBag.Person in your controller:

```
  ViewBag.Person= new SelectList( db.Users.Where(u => u.Id == Person), "idPerson", "LibellePerson");
```

your view:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Person", null, string.Empty, new { id = "Person", @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Thank you, I am going to make changes.